# Xcode unit test error after renaming project: Could not determine bundle identifier for /.../[projectName].app

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

Running Xcode 9. I encountered this error after renaming my project differently from the app name as specified in the target definition. Didn't realize this was a no-no. The error kept appearing even after I renamed the project back to match the target definition.

Comment: Did you try clear build (cmd + shift + alt + k )?

Comment: Yes for some reason that does not remove the offending file (see below).

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was an app called [badProjectName].app that was created under /Users/[userName]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[projectFolderName]-[randomStrings]/Build/Products/Debug when building and running my tests after renaming differently from the actual app name (as defined in the target). The mere presence of this app caused it to fail with this error. It was only after I deleted [badProjectName].app from that directory (along with associated test runner apps that were created) did the error go away. So be careful about renaming your project!